# Jquery Ajax call taking longer time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http, iis

I have **`jQuery AJAX`** request which post large amount of data (300B). But it is taking longer time to reach the request to that **`API`**. It means request is taking time to reach a server  **`IIS`** OR **`IIS`** to **`API`**.

What should I do to minimize this time. When I reduce data to 100B then it gives response very fast.

Note: **`API`** domain is **`HTTPS`** based.

Below is the ajax code which i am using

```
var res = escape(pageSource);    
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "abc.com/Api/Deatils",
                data: { Id: id, url: taburl, pageSource: res },
                crossDomain: true,
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {

                        $("#lblMessage").text(msg.message);
                },
                error: function (jxhr) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is your problem and what are all you are trying?please update some Code.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the data you send and the process, including relevant code.For example, sometimes it happens that a large Json takes long time to be parsed at server. But you're not telling us anything about the data, configuration, or what are you trying to do. Please edit your question.

Comment: 300B (bytes) is really not a lot of data. Since we don't know the code or the circumstances we can't give any advice about what the cause of the slow operation is or the solution should be, however HTTPs is almost certainly not a related factor.

Comment: I have edited my questions and added a code which i am using. For your reference, I am sending a string data not a json.

Comment: why are you using async: false? It's deprecated and there's no reason for it here. It just creates a poor user experience by locking the UI until the request completes. Ajax requests are intended to be async and there's almost never a reason to prevent this. Also, how big exactly is the time delay you're experiencing when you upload an extra 200 bytes of data (this is a _negligible_ quantity by modern standards)? What is the speed of the network connection involved?

Comment: @Adyson I am experiencing 10 second of delay with extra 200 bytes of data. Network connection is not an issue as i have check with 15 MBPS networks. As i have check with log file, it taking time to reach to server IIS.

Comment: apart from the unnecessary async: false there's nothing obviously wrong with your JavaScript code. Possibly the server config is at issue. It's very hard to say, you probably just have to try and narrow it down some more. Try making the exact same request using another tool such as PostMan and see if it makes any difference. Try from a different browser, different machine, different location etc and see if varying any of these factors has an impact. Also does the server endpoint belong to you?

Comment: @ADyson I have tried with postman with different location, machine etc, but not worked. And yes I have server endpoint access with me as it is my own server. I think there should be some settings at IIS end, which i need to set. Let me check that in more detail